# Sum of Fourier series members with odd indices

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the following Fourier series for the function $f(x) = e^x$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$
$$
\frac{e^{\pi} - e^{-\pi}}{2\pi}  + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^n(e^{\pi} - e^{-\pi})}{\pi(n^2 + 1)}\cos nx +  \frac{n(-1)^n(e^{-\pi} - e^{\pi})}{\pi(n^2 + 1)} \sin nx\right]
$$
I want to find the following sum on $(-\pi, \pi)$:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(a_{2n + 1}\cos(2n + 1)x + b_{2n + 1}\sin(2n + 1)x)
$$
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Shift $f(t)$ as much as half its period to obtain $f(t-\pi)$ and then find the Fourier series of $f(t)-f(t-\pi)$.

Comment: should I find the Fourier series of $f(t) - f(t - \pi) = e^t(1 - e^{-\pi})$ ?

Comment: Is this equality for $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: Yes, $f(t - \pi) = e^{t - \pi}$ or what did you mean by "shift" ?

Comment: Note that using the shift, $f(t-\pi)$ and $f(t)-f(t-\pi)$ become discontinuous in $t=0$ while $e^t(1-e^{-\pi})$ does not.

Comment: Also apply the shift only on the Fourier coefficients of $f(t)$.

Comment: What did you mean by $f(t)$ ? Fourier series for function $f(x) = e^x$ ?

Comment: Oops, yes :) By $f(t)$ I everywhere mean $f(x)$.

Comment: Do you substitute $x\to x-\pi$ in the Fourier series representation of $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, I almost done it. I got that the desired row is equal to $2^{-1}e^{x}(1 - e^{-\pi})$ on $(-\pi, \pi)$. Am i right ?

Comment: No because $$f(x-\pi)=\frac{e^{\pi} - e^{-\pi}}{2\pi}  + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(e^{\pi} - e^{-\pi})}{\pi(n^2 + 1)}\cos nx +  \frac{n(e^{-\pi} - e^{\pi})}{\pi(n^2 + 1)} \sin nx\right]
$$